# Notification of compliance status for Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ec2, notifications

I want to know if there is a solution to get notifications by mail about the compliance status of Amazon EC2?
Is it possible to schedule a workflow , to get every week one email notification with a list of all Amazon EC2 and his compliance status ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe more what compliance status of EC2 is? Patch?

Comment: Yes Exactly , compliance status with patch

Comment: Then you can use SSM, Config, SNS. Like this doc. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/quick-setup-config.html